# How to save a random number to mysql in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

Please can anybody help i want to generate randoms strings base on requested numbers and store them to a table in my mysql database using the MVC pattern of codeigniter. Thanks
The controller

```
public function generate()
    {
$this->news_model->generate_pin();
        $this->load->helper('string');
      echo random_string('alnum',15);
```

the model

```
public function generate_pin(){

      $this->load->helper('string');
   $this->db->insert('pin', $number);
```

but nothing is happening also i want it to run 10 array at a time

Comment: Can you have a sample flow on the "requested numbers"?

However, I think this is a simple insert of `rand()` to a CI model.

Comment: yeah but can you put me through on how to insert the rand and also how to input a speck number required, generate it and insert into the database

Comment: speck number? Did you mean the length?

Comment: No the length i wnat to be able to generate 10 number 5 number depending on the amount i want and store it to the database

Comment: This is my controller $this->load->helper('string');
        echo random_string('alnum',15); and my model is   $data = array(
           random_string
        );
      
   $this->db->insert('pin', $data); 
but nothing is going to my database

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add additional code and/or details to the question, so it is more visible. Then delete the redundant comment(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle any application logic in the controller instead of in the model. This example would insert 10 randomly generated strings into a database table:

```
// THE CONTROLLER
public function generate() 
{
    // LOAD THE STRING HELPER
    $this->load->helper('string');

    $pins = array(); // HOLDER OF PIN CODES 
    $num_pins = 10; // THE NUMBER OF PIN CODES YOU WANT TO GENERATE
    $len_pins = 15; // THE LENGTH OF THE PIN CODES YOU WANT TO GENERATE

    // LOOP and generate the PIN codes
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_pins; $i++) {
        //REPLACE 'pin_fieldname' WITH WHATEVER FIELD NAME YOU HAVE IN YOUR TABLE 'pin'
        $pins[] = array('pin_fieldname'=>random_string('alnum', $len_pins));
        //IF YOU WANT TO HAVE DIFFERENT LENGTHS OF YOUR PIN CODES 
        //YOU CAN PUT SOME LOGIC HERE TO CHANGE $len_pins
        // $len_pins = {WHATEVER NUMBER};    
    }   

    // INSERT THE PINS INTO THE DATABASE
    if($this->news_model->insert_pins($pins)){
        // SUCCESS INSERT... DO SOMETHING...    
    } else {
        // FAILED INSERT.. DO SOMETHING...
    }
}
```

AND the model:

```
// THE MODEL
public function insert_pins($pins){
    // LOAD THE DATABASE YOU WANT TO USE (IF NOT ALREADY DONE ELSEWHERE)
    $this->db = $this->load->database(); //https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html
    return $this->db->insert_batch('pin', $pins);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael but i am getting error with $len_pins and for() lines in my controller i got Message: syntax error, unexpected '$len_pins' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put `;` after the variable names... let me know if it works for you know. Have updated the answer..

Comment: Hi Micheal K thanks for the help. Please i am trying to do two things but seems not getting something right one worked but the other is not. 1. I want to verify the pin on the registration page if it exist in the database and has not been used, 2. If yes then i want to update the pin table and status. This was what i used in php and it worked but not on CI: $check = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'X' FROM pin WHERE  pin= '".$pin."' and status = '0'");
     if ($check->num_rows != 1) {
      $dupPin = 'true';
     }

Comment: and i have this for CI model: function pin_verification($pin)
 {
  $query = $this->db->get_where('pin',array('pin'=>$pin));
  return $query->num_rows();
 }